# Unable to understand PDF Function (type 4) stream syntax

Tags: pdf

```
stream
{ 360 mul sin
2 div
exch 360 mul sin
2 div
add
}
endstream
```

Can someone please explain this syntax to me?

Comment: You've asked a PDF related question before, which has been answered perfectly well (not by me). But you missed to accept or upvote the answer. People will be hesitant to deal with your questions if you do not give proper feedback or appreciation.

Comment: Thanks, for your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't look like PDF to me:

- `stream` and `endstream` are PDF keywords, yes.
- But the rest rather looks like PostScript.

So `stream` and `endstream` could also be PostScript variables or functions, defined elsewhere (before) in the same code...

---

As PostScript, the code means:

- `{` and `}` are just separators that structure the code into blocks
- `360 mul sin`: multiply by 360 (*multiply what?* => the value that's topmost on the stack), compute the sinus value for the result, and put this as topmost on the stack.
- `2 div`: divide the topmost value on the stack by 2.
- `exch 360 mul sin`: swap the 2 topmost items on the stack, multiply the item that's now topmost by 360, compute the sinus of it and put it back on the stack.
- `2 div`: divide the topmost value on the stack by 2.
- `add`: add the 2 topmost values on the stack.

---

**Update:**

Ouch!

I had completely forgotten about the details of the (very limited) PostScript *function objects* which the PDF spec allows inside PDF documents. These represent self-contained and static numerical transformations.

So my above explanation of the PostScript code as a calculator function is still valid, and it looks to me like describing a 'spot function' for a halftone screen. (However, `stream` and `endstream` in this context of course do keep their original meanings as PDF keywords, and the curly braces `{` and `}` are *required* to enclose the function definition.)

Since the PDF spec for these PostScript function objects does not allow the use of *arrays*, *variables*, *names* or *strings*, but only *integers*, *reals* and *booleans* as values, the processing of these code segments doesn't require a fully fledged PostScript interpreter, and this statement in the spec:

> *"PDF is not a programming language, and a PDF file is not a program."*

does still apply and makes still the PDF language very different from PostScript (which is a *programming* language, and PS files *are* programs).

Keeping in mind, that PostScript is a stack-based language, and understanding its code by thinking of a pocket calculator that uses [*'reverse Polish notation'*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) conventions will help you wrapping your mind around this topic...

Comment: Thanks for the details. But, this is part of PDF specification and only this much details is there in PDF example which is as follows.    10 0 obj
<< /FunctionType 4
/Domain [ −1.0 1.0 −1.0 1.0 ]
/Range [ −1.0 1.0 ]
/Length 71
>>
stream
{ 360 mul sin
2 div
exch 360 mul sin
2 div
add
}
endstream
endobj

Comment: @user1184384: You are right. I had completely forgotten about the limited PostScript *function objects* which are allowed by the PDF spec inside PDF code.

Comment: Your latest update on my question explained everything I wanted to know.

Answer (score 2):

Its a postscript program which executes on the raw data to provide the end values. You will need a Postscript parser to handle it

Comment: My problem was that, I could't understand this syntax. As pdf reference suggest it interpret these subset(postscript) operators differently. Type 4 (PostScript Calculator) Functions. (pdf_reference_1-7.pdf, Page number 175). Yes, I have to implement these subset operators myself.